# SAS: replicate rows and iterate over columns

Tags: sas

I'd like to replicate and modify specific rows in the table.

before:

```
xyz_id | letter | Col_1 | Col_2|
1 | Z | V1 | W1 |
2 | Z | V2 | W2 |
3 | Z | V3 | W3 |
```

after:

```
xyz_id | letter | Col_1 | Col_2|
1 | A | V1.1 | W1.1 |
1 | B | V1.1 | W1.1 |
1 | C | V1.1 | W1.1 |
2 | A | V2.1 | W2.1 |
2 | B | V2.1 | W2.1 |
2 | C | V2.1 | W2.1 |
3 | A | V3.1 | W3.1 |
3 | B | V3.1 | W3.1 |
3 | C | V3.1 | W3.1 |
```

I've prepared the following code:

```
data test2;
        set test;
        
        array letters {8} $8 _temporary_ ('A', 'B', 'C');
        array weights {8}  _temporary_ (1,2,3);
        array nvars {2} Col_1 Col_2;

        do i = 1 to 8;
            letter = letters(i);

            do j=1 to 2;
                nvar{j} = nvar{j} * weights(i);
            end;

            output;
        end;
          drop i;
run;
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference the `nvar` array in the `j` loop, but the array is called `nvars`.

`Col_1` and `Col_2` are characters (e.g. 'V1'), so you cannot multiply these by a number and expect a valid result.

Your `letters` and `weights` arrays do not have enough values defined for the number of elements (3 vs 8).

Comment: nvar vs nvars... That was a problem;/ Thank you so much!